# ng-click= checkPhoneError() does not get called

Tags: html, angularjs

I am newbie and inherited this code. When I click on the Call button checkPhoneError() does not get called. What is missing here? Thanks

```
    <ion-nav-title>Status: {{name}}
        <a href="{{::getPhoneNumber()}}" class="blue" ng-show="::showCallButton">
            <div id="callArea"
                class="button"
                ng-class="::getCallButtonColor()">
                Call
            </div>
        </a>
        <div id="buttonOverlay" ng-click="checkPhoneError()"></div>
    </ion-nav-title>
```

This is the Controller Code. So when the call button is clicked I hope to break to this funciton:

```
    $scope.checkPhoneError = function () {
      if (phoneNumberError) {
        displayError();
        $fileLogger.log("error", "There is no phone number for " + analysis.name);
      }
      else if ($scope.alertLevel != '') {
        PaymentService.call(analysis.name, $scope.alertLevel);
      }
    };
```

Sorry I should have added this too, I did not realize what all was needed for people to get full context. Here is my size of the button from the CSS file. Yes I can click and the control goes to the phone and I can make a call. What I want is to know that the phone call happened. BTW this a cordova/ionic app running on Android phone:

```
#buttonOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

I Googled and got some hint and tried this. Now I can break into my function but the call button does not show :(. However when I hover there the cursor becomes live(becomes a hand) and I can click the execution breaks into my function, now only if I can see the call button.

```
<ion-nav-title>Status: {{name}}
    <div id="buttonOverlay" ng-click="checkPhoneError()">
        <a href="{{::getPhoneNumber()}}" class="blue" ng-show="::showCallButton">
            <div id="callArea"
                class="button"
                ng-class="::getCallButtonColor()">
                Call
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</ion-nav-title>
```

Finally I hit the solution thanks to Google!! Here is the working code. So what was happening was a-tag will set the link and make it automatically clickable. So the default ng-click was masking my ng-click. All I had to do was to override the default ng-click with my own.

```
<ion-nav-title>Status: {{name}}
    <a href="{{::getPhoneNumber()}}" class="blue" ng-click="checkPhoneError()" ng-show="::showCallButton">
        <div id="callArea"
            class="button"
            ng-class="::getCallButtonColor()">
            Call
        </div>
    </a>
    <div id="buttonOverlay" ></div>
</ion-nav-title>
```

Comment: How about your controller? could you please provide the controller code also.

Comment: Can u confirm that you have ng - app and ng - controller mentioned in the right places?

Comment: Sorry I did not get the meaning of no - app and no - controller. However I can confirm this is 99% working code. I just added the Call button and hope take control at the function checkPhoneError()  when clicked.

Comment: The ng-click is on a div that have no content at all and thus probably has a height of 0 pixel. Are you sure you managed to click on it? What happens when you add a bunch of text inside the div to make it big on the screen, and then click on it?

Comment: @JAAulde I see you have edited but I see the edit in my comment part only not in the code, is that right? Please confirm as I am new to the Stackoverflow

Comment: Yes @SanthoshKumar I removed the first paragaraph of your question from the code block

Comment: This question has been answered and it can be closed. Thanks for all those commented and pushed me to a solution

Answer (score 0):

Finally I hit the solution thanks to Google!! Here is the working code. So what was happening was a-tag will set the link and make it automatically clickable. So the default ng-click was masking my ng-click. All I had to do was to override the default ng-click with my own.

```
<ion-nav-title>Status: {{name}}
    <a href="{{::getPhoneNumber()}}" class="blue" ng-click="checkPhoneError()" ng-show="::showCallButton">
        <div id="callArea"
            class="button"
            ng-class="::getCallButtonColor()">
            Call
        </div>
    </a>
    <div id="buttonOverlay" ></div>
</ion-nav-title>
```